# Search by a numerical value in Mongoose and Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, mongodb, mongoose

There is a search function in front-end that searches through multiple fields at once also for partial search.

For example, if there are two fields, **name** and **address** as string values:

```
   const aggregateOptions = [];

   aggregateOptions.push({
        $match: {
          $or: [
            { name: { $regex: req.query.name, $options: 'i' } },
            { address: { $regex: req.query.address, $options: 'i' } },
         ],
       },
   });
```

In this case, if there is an array of objects of this form:

```
myArray = [{name: "Mike", address: "123 street"}, 
           {name: "Michele", address: "66 street"}
          ];
```

- if we write in the searchbox "Mi" - it should return both objects because both names start with "Mi
- if we write "street" - again, both because both contain that substring inside address
- if we write "Mik" - it should return only the first object

It works fine for strings but I don't know to do it if one field is numerical, for example:

```
myArray = [{name: "Mike", address: "123 street", age: 19}, 
           {name: "Michele", address: "66 street", age: 18}
          ];
```

In this case:

- if we write "1" it should return both because both ages contain that substring (also there is a "1! inside first object's address
- if we write "18" it should return only the second object

I've tried several methods but without success:

1.

```
   aggregateOptions.push({
        $match: {
          $or: [
            { name: { $regex: req.query.name, $options: 'i' } },
            { address: { $regex: req.query.address, $options: 'i' } },
            { age: { $regex: req.query.age, $options: 'i' } }, // same approach as above - doesn't work
         ],
       },
   });
```

2. 

```
   aggregateOptions.push({
        $match: {
          $or: [
            { name: { $regex: req.query.name, $options: 'i' } },
            { address: { $regex: req.query.address, $options: 'i' } },
            { age: { $regex: req.query.age.toString() } }, // convert number to string - nope
         ],
       },
   });
```

3. 

```
 aggregateOptions.push({
        $addFields: {
          ageString: { $toString: '$age' }, // save it as a string before
        },
      });

 aggregateOptions.push({
            $match: {
              $or: [
                { name: { $regex: req.query.name, $options: 'i' } },
                { address: { $regex: req.query.address, $options: 'i' } },
               { ageString: { $regex: req.query.age.toString() } }, // still not working
             ], 
           },
       });
```

Any suggestions?